# How to create a secure internal route in the CloudFoundry environment (Swisscom AppCloud)

Tags: dns, routes, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I would like to create a secure **internal** route between two applications within the same space/organization. It should never be possible to reach the Node.js application from the outside. My Java application connects via HTTP to the Node application (running on express).

I have now tried to setup the desired configuration by creating a route called `example-route.apps.internal` and assigned it to the Node application. As a next step, I've opened the port (I've tried `443`, `80`, `8080`) in the network configuration of the Java application (with the destination being the Node app). I restaged both applications.

Then, I opened a Java connection to the link `http://example-route.apps.internal/test123`. I've also tried to use `https`. The result was the same. Java refused to conncet to this URL.

Now, the following questions:

- How can I properly set up this communication? Should I resolve this internal DNS somehow? Which port is the correct one if I just use the port of the env variable? How should I read this port from the other application?
- How secure is the communication, if HTTP is used instead of HTTPS? (I assume HTTPS is not possible internally). Is it as safe as an HTTPS connection from the outside? Which devices are between, how far out does the connection go?

Thank you!

Comment: In addition to the very nice answer of @DanielMikusa, I would like to share the following blog article link, which describes the container-to-container networking specifically on the Swisscom App Cloud: https://ict.swisscom.ch/2018/05/container-networking-with-cloud-foundry/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're almost there.

> Then, I opened a Java connection to the link http://example-route.apps.internal/test123. I've also tried to use https. The result was the same. Java refused to conncet to this URL.

You should use `http://example-route.apps.internal:8080/test123`. Your app is set to listen on $PORT, which is always 8080 in current versions of CF.

Normally you don't need to worry about this because your traffic goes in through Gorouter which translates for you (maps external port 80 -> internal 8080). With internal routes, traffic is direct so there is no transformation. That's why you need to use port 8080 in your URL.

Alternatively, you could use a service discovery mechanism like Eureka or Consul, but it's not a requirement. In this case, the service would know it's listening on 8080 and register that in the registry.

As far as HTTPS, that's tricky. Your app is only listening on 80/HTTP. You would have to change it to listen on 443/HTTPS, but then you need certs and different server configuration. It's technically possible, but it's a whole can of worms.

In some newer versions, Envoy is present and accepts HTTPS traffic into a container, can make HTTPS easier but it's still not a slam dunk (at the time of writing, at least). I expect this will get better in the future.

> Should I resolve this internal DNS somehow?

Internal DNS helps with locating your other apps, not the port. Otherwise you'd need to manage IP addresses, which change often, and that would require something like Eureka or Consul.

> Which port is the correct one if I just use the port of the env variable?

See above.

> How should I read this port from the other application?

It's always 8080 at the moment, and has been for multiple years. It's unlikely to change, so you could probably hard code or set it in a config file safely.

> How secure is the communication, if HTTP is used instead of HTTPS? (I assume HTTPS is not possible internally).
>   Is it as safe as an HTTPS connection from the outside? Which devices are between, how far out does the connection go?

Traffic would not be accessible externally as it wouldn't leave the Cell in some cases or worst case it goes between two Cells, but traffic would be visible internally since it's not encrypted. That means you need to have more trust on your CF provider, who would have access to internal traffic.

If it were HTTPS, only someone with the key would be able to decrypt it. You would still have to trust your provider though as they could likely get the key & use it to decrypt traffic. It would just be more work for them than if traffic is unencrypted.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great, thanks! This is very helpful. I got it to work like this! The only thing I was wondering: You mentioned, the worst case is, that the traffic goes between two cells. But those cells are always internally routed, right? So, it won't ever leave the data center?

Comment: Usually Cells are on the same network, when they are in the same AZ, or in the same data center if the CF foundation has multiple AZs. I can only speak in general terms though, you would have to confirm with your operators.

Comment: This helped me a lot !!!